# Buildfire: Set title bar text programmatically

Tags: javascript, buildfire

Is there a method to set the top title bar text inside the widget on a buildfire plugin? I have not been able to find much except how to show or hide the bar.

`buildfire.appearance.titlebar.show()`

Is there something like `buildfire.appearance.titlebar.text("abc")` I haven't found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can change the Title as you enter into a sub section of your plugin if you use Breadcrumbs 
ref https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Breadcrumbs

Secondly, If you control navigation. You can set the Title when you navigate to it.
ref https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigateto-plugindata